# Error: Node Sass Not Supported in Current Environment

Tags: node.js, terminal, gulp, bower

Gulping had been working just fine until this morning. I don't know what I should install, update or uninstall to get my local environment to work again. Config: Catalina 10.15.7 Node 15.0.1 Gulp CLI v 2.3.0 Local v 4..0.2
I noticed that building my scripts was giving me errors, so I uninstalled npm and reinstalled. Now when I gulp, Im getting these errors:

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be a version issue of some dependent packages. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74304916/685935

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that I need to roll back to v 14.15.0 of node ---> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

Deleted node_modules in my target directory, and reinstalled. Ran `npm audit fix`, then did a fresh gulp and everything worked fine