# Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

Tags: npm, node-sass

this what VSC terminal show me

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

i tried some solutions in stack overflow:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

and

```
npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass
```

but does't work with , i saw some people talk about node version if support sass or not,
im using `v16.14.0` it's LTS version should that support i guess,
i hope someone can help and THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost like it's trying to install the 4.x branch which only supports up to Node 14.

Try installing the 7.0.1 (current latest).

```
npm i node-sass@7.0.1
```

I'd recommend going ahead and wiping `node_modules` prior to installing just to be safe.

If that doesn't work, can you please post the entire output in the comment?

Comment: doesn't work and still the same ERROR

Comment: So yeah, I've personally had many issues with node-sass just because it's older. Usually my solution is to rollback to Node v14 LTS using something like NVM. but that's not always the best. Is there any way you can swap to the proper [sass library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) or is this out of your control?

Comment: It also looks like you're running yarn? This is counter to your original post which uses NPM. 
Also gulp, which means there's some sort of loader no? Having the entire configuration would help us better help you.

Comment: Can you please paste those to something like Ghostbin, or hastebin, or anything? Attempting to read a log like that is absolutely terrible.

Comment: run yarn result **https://www.klgrth.io/paste/h77qy**

Comment: after it run `yarn build` and result **https://www.klgrth.io/paste/yqxhr**

Comment: That's a completely different issue, you don't have python 2 installed.

Comment: but i have python 3.10 installed

Comment: Python 3 != Python 2. This is a common issue, but your logs indicate it's looking for Python 2, so you need [Python 2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/).

Comment: Thanks @MattHatcher. Pointing out the python version issue helped me figure out I had the wrong version of Node selected in nodist.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by forcing Visual Studio to use the node version I installed instead of VS installed version of node:

Go to Visual Studio, Tools -> Options, Project and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> External Web Tools, and move the `$(PATH)` to the second place below `.\node_modules\.bin` and above `$(VSInstalledExternalTools)`. Restart Visual Studio.

Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745146/379279).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the errors due to node-sass:

```
 1. Remove "sass" and "sass-loader" from package.json
 2. rm -rf node_modules
 3. npm install
 4. npm install sass --save-dev
 5. npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

The versions of some packages is enforced in package.json. The solution is to re-add them by letting npm to establish their right version for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was updated my nodejs version 18.18 then this error occured to me. I'm using webpack with the version of 5 and node-sass with the version of 7. But I had no sass module.

The solution for me was installing the sass.

npm i sass --save-dev